# Modify IE 'Internet Options' in HP UFT (QTP)

Tags: automated-testing, qtp, hp-uft

I need to ensure that the "**Use automatic configuration**" checkbox is set to **off** before my script starts.  Group policy keeps changing this.

How can I get into the "*Internet Options*" menu?  It is not recording the click on the `cog` icon.  The shortcut keys are <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>.

This is what I've tried:

```
Browser("NetStar Login").Dialog("Internet Options").WinTab("SysTabControl32").Select "Connections"
Browser("NetStar Login").Dialog("Internet Options").WinButton("LAN settings").Click
Browser("NetStar Login").Dialog("Internet Options").Dialog("Local Area Network (LAN)").WinCheckBox("Use automatic configuration").Set "OFF"
Browser("NetStar Login").Dialog("Internet Options").Dialog("Local Area Network (LAN)").WinButton("OK").Click
Browser("NetStar Login").Dialog("Internet Options").WinButton("OK").Click
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved this.  Would love to hear better solutions:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.SendKeys("+{TAB}") 'shift + tab
wait(1)
WshShell.SendKeys("{RIGHT}")'right arrow
wait(1)
WshShell.SendKeys("{RIGHT}")'right arrow
wait(1)
WshShell.SendKeys(Chr(13))  'enter
wait(1)
WshShell.SendKeys("o")      'o
```